# Prove $\int^a_0 x(a^2-x^2)^{\nu-1} I_0(b x)dx= 2^{\nu-1}a^\nu b^{-\nu}\Gamma(\nu)I_\nu(a b)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How can I prove the following equality?

> $$ \int^a_0 x\left(a^2-x^2\right)^{\nu-1} I_0\left(b x\right)dx=
> 2^{\nu-1}a^\nu b^{-\nu}\Gamma\left(\nu\right)I_\nu\left(a b\right),
> $$
>   under the condition $a>0$, $b>0$ $\nu>0$, where $I_\nu(\cdot)$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $\nu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to show this is by series expansion.  First, rescale the integral to get

$$a^{\nu+1} \int_0^1 du \, u (1-u^2)^{v-1} I_0(a b u) $$

Expand the Bessel into a series:

$$a^{\nu+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a b/2)^{2 k}}{k!^2} \int_0^1 du \, u^{2 k+1} (1-u^2)^{\nu-1} $$

The integral is a beta function:

$$\int_0^1 du \, u^{2 k+1} (1-u^2)^{\nu-1} = \frac12 \int_0^1 dv \, v^k (1-v)^{\nu-1} = \frac12 \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(\nu)}{\Gamma(k+\nu+1)} $$

The integral is now a sum:

$$\frac12 a^{\nu+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a b/2)^{2 k}}{k!^2} \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(\nu)}{\Gamma(k+\nu+1)} = \frac12 \Gamma(\nu) a^{\nu+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a b/2)^{2 k}}{k! \Gamma(k+\nu+1)}  $$

We are almost there.  Now let's multiply and divide by a factor that will bring us our new Bessel:

$$\frac12 \Gamma(\nu) a^{\nu+1} \left (\frac{2}{a b}\right )^{\nu} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a b/2)^{2 k+\nu}}{k! \Gamma(k+\nu+1)} = 2^{\nu-1} \Gamma(\nu)\frac{a}{b^{\nu}} I_{\nu}(a b)$$

which is the value of the integral.

**REMARK**

The OP's value for the integral is not correct.  One can tell by simple dimensional analysis.  For instance, if $a$ is in unit of length, then $b$ must be in units of inverse length.  The integral itself is in units of length to the $\nu+1$ power.  The OP's result, however, has units of length to the $2 \nu$ power.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice answer! But I couldn't understand the remark. How should I modify the OP?

Comment: @S.Miyabe: The OP in this case is you.  I'd rather address you as the OP to avoid being personal.  Do you understand dimansional analysis?  If you don't, learn it!  It will save you hours of madness by providing a quick check on your integral.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I am the OP. I know $a$ and $b$ are not in the same dimension. So the notation $a$ and $b$ might not be appropriate because they can suggest the same dimension.

Comment: @S.Miyabe: no, the notation is fine.  Just know where you are and keep the dimensions of your constants in mind as you work through to your result.